# ASP include virtual not updating

Tags: asp-classic

I'm looking after a site that was written in ASP. The server is an Apache server using Chillisoft to run the ASP code.

We have content that has to appear in multiple locations. To make things simple we are using the `<!-- #include virtual = "/file/location/file.asp" -->` to include the content of file.asp in the current page (Let's call this Page B).

The problem comes when we update file.asp. If we goto the file.asp page the updated content appears fine. However if we goto Page B the new updated content that appears on file.asp does not appear, UNLESS we go into the Page B.asp file, add a line to the code and save it, then the new content from file.asp appears on Page B.

I am familiar with includes in PHP and I've never seen this behavior before but this is my first time working with ASP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is Chillisoft caching the page server-side?

Comment: This. Or maybe apache is cacheing. It's easy to test; edit the include, restart apache and see if the change is shown on all pages.